# document scripts not being part of modules in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I looked for several packages (sphinx-gallery, autoprogram,...), but found nothing on how to easily use a docstring from a python script for documentation. So I somehow want to do `autodoc` on a specific file.

Is somebody aware of the possibility to automatically generate sphinx documentation out of python scripts?

Like I have a docstring in the beginning of the script and maybe some functions with docstrings in there and just want to autogenerate some documentation like I can do with the `.. automodule::`directive, but unfortunately that won't work for relative paths / scripts.

#### EDIT:

The scripts I want to create some docstrings out are not cli scripts, it are just some python scripts which are getting called by a cron job in general. So unfortunately autoprogram won't help here as far as I see.

#### EDIT2:

Okay, so now I got a little bit clearer on that after re-reading the documentation and trying around. What I wanted to do is automatically taking the docstring of a python file and put that to documentation **without executing** the whole file (because for some reasons I can't or don't want to hide everything behind a main routine). I got autodoc to document a specific file (there was some misconfiguration why that didn't worked), but like stated in its documentation, it executes the file. That's my true problem right here. I'd be happy if one has a solution to achieve this, but would totally understand if this is not possible without big effort.

Comment: What do you mean by "found nothing"? Why can't you use sphinx-autoprogram? https://sphinxcontrib-autoprogram.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Sorry, edited the question :)

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example, else read the first note in autodocs documentation http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html

Comment: I still don't understand why you cannot use sphinxcontrib-autoprogram. What is the difference between CLI scripts and "just some python scripts which are getting called by a cron job in general"?

Comment: @mzjn autoprogram requires some kind of argparse params, I wanted to document a script which does something without user input.

Comment: @StevePiercy yes, you're right. I'll edit the answer, sorry for not responding so long, had a lot to do.

Comment: Why do you say "for some reasons I can't or don't want to hide everything behind a main routine"? What are those reasons? If you have a Python module that you also want to use as a script, you should use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` check. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html?highlight=__main__#module-__main__.

Comment: To clarify: we don't talk about modules which I want to use as scripts, we talk about scripts without input from the user, but I would like to document each one of them.

These are kind of long scripts which I don't want to hide behind a `__main__` routine (I know this would be best practice, but they are *always* main) for not unneccessary putting more intend into it, keep readibility and pep8-conformity.

Answer (score 1):

> What I wanted to do is automatically taking the docstring of a python file and put that to documentation without executing the whole file.

You cannot do that.  To get the docstring from a module, the module needs to be imported.  Importing the module executes the whole file.

If you don't want code to be executed upon a "simple import", you can use a `if __name__ == __name__` block or [setuptools `entry_point`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) based automatic script generation.