# Sphinx: documenting entrypoints (console scripts) of a python library

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I am developing a small python 3.10 library. I have integrated Sphinx 5.0 to document the project functions, classes, modules etc. This runs on a ubuntu container. The documentation  is working. The point that confuses me is how to properly document the use of the library multiple entrypoints?

More specifically, in my `setup.cfg`, I wrote the following:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    crumbs-fit-sdm = crumbs.sdm.fit:main
```

So that after installation the user can type in the terminal eg `crumbs-fit-sdm input -v` without having to locate the `.py` file.

How to have Sphinx properly (and automatically) document this feature along with the available options?

Comment: You can document console scripts, but not by using autodoc (if that is what you mean). Sphinx with autodoc documents *modules* by importing them. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21003048/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49179200/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10886841/407651

Comment: That answers my question, thank you :)